# Creating a +50Gb Docker image and then running the container on an Azure Service?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to containerize an opensource llm. I finally managed to create a docker image of it inside a VM since it was the only place with enough memory for it. However, the image is 50 Gb and more, and Azure Container Instances documentation says its max size for images is 15 Gb.
Is there an Azure service that I can use to build a large image and then run a container (and other containers) based on the large image?

So far I have the image in a VM, but the VM keeps unmounting the disk whenever it is shutdown for the night. I was told not to use a VM anyway, and now it's running out of space. I did then move the image into Azure Container Registry for safekeeping and in preparation for the ACI, but then I read the documentation about the image size limit. Ideally, creating the image and running the containers would happen entirely in some Azure service. I was told not to use a VM, so what else can I use to do this?

Comment: IMO making a +50Gb docker image is the wrong path to take. I assume it contains a data set of some kind. Maybe it needs to be rethink in better solution.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal, but I don't know how else to run it without downloading the entire model every time, and my own computer can't handle the memory stress in either running the code or building the container image

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPU container. However, GPU container is not available by default to all subscriptions and you have to raise a customer support ticket to enable it.

Documentation link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-gpu

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Although ACI has a limitation of 15Gb per image size, do you know if the GPU versions will overcome that?

Comment: There is no hard limit, larger image size may cause timeout while downloading the image. You can try with 20GB, 30GB, and gradually increase the size.